# Discord.js bot random presence and status not showing nor changing when the bot starts

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to make a random bot *presence/status* change using Discord.js v13 that changes every 15 minutes. The problem I'm facing with my code is that the custom status and presence don't show when I first start the bot, I have to wait 15 minutes for it to show up and start changing.

Here is the code:

```js
client.on("ready", async () => {
    let servers = await client.guilds.cache.size
    let servercount = await client.guilds.cache.reduce((a,b) => a+b.memberCount, 0 )
    const statusArray = [
    {
        type: 'WATCHING',
        content: `${servers} servers`,
        status: 'online'
    },
    {
        type: 'PLAYING',
        content: `with my ${servercount} friends`,
        status: 'online'
    }
    ];
    async function pickPresence() {
        const option = Math.floor(Math.random() * statusArray.length);
        try {
            await client.user.setPresence({
                activities: [
                {
                    name: statusArray[option].content,
                    type: statusArray[option].type,
                    url: statusArray[option].url
                },
            ],
            status: statusArray[option].status
            }); 
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
    setInterval(pickPresence, 1000*60*15);
});
```

Any ideas as to why it doesn't work instantly when I start the bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval` actually waits for the specified delay (15 minutes) before executing the code in the function for the first time. So all you need to do is simply add `pickPresence()` on the line before the `setInterval`.

```
pickPresence();
setInterval(pickPresence, 1000*60*15);
```